# Authentication in Flask app using flask-simpleldap

Tags: python, authentication, flask, ldap, flask-login

I am trying to build user authentication in  Flask app. The authentication needs to be done using the LDAP server. The documentation given on [this](http://flask-simpleldap.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
link is not very clear. It asks for the `LDAP_USERNAME` and `LDAP_PASSWORD`. Is this same as as username and password for  a user? I want to fetch this from the login page which I was going to do using `request.forms`. :

```
@app.route('/login')
 def login():
   user = request.form['user_name']
   password = request.form['password']
   ldap_authenticate_user(user, password)
```

Has anyone successfully used the Flask-LDAP using flask-simpleldap ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote flask-simpleldap and just found this, I hope this will be useful for someone. LDAP_USERNAME and LDAP_PASSWORD are the credentials you use to [bind](https://www.ldap.com/the-ldap-bind-operation) to a directory server. It's usually a service account and it's the account that will be used to run queries against the directory server, e.g. search for users/groups, bind a user account etc.

There are some [example apps](https://github.com/admiralobvious/flask-simpleldap/tree/master/examples) in the github repo that should help you understand a bit better.

Comment: Thanks. The significance of this user_name and password was not clear from the documentation. One question though. Can the username and password of a user be used to bind to a directory server?

Comment: @admiralobvious is there anyway to test this  bind user connection?  It can get tricky with TLS, different ldap implementations, etc.

Comment: I split this out to a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306923/python-flasksimple-ldap-wont-bind)  to hopefully sort my bind issues:

Comment: You should be able to bind with any active user account, person or service.

Tools like ApacheDirectoryStudio allow you to test these connections before enshrining the config in a python script.  Lets you sort out the userid (DN actually) and password to bind with, base DN and things like the user and group DNs.