# python - flask_simpleldap won't bind

Tags: python, ldap

I'm using [flask_simpleldap](https://github.com/admiralobvious/flask-simpleldap) and am struggling to get a bind connection to do anything useful.

My LDAP server is active directory.

The stripped down code looks as follows, and looks almost identical to [the example](https://github.com/admiralobvious/flask-simpleldap/blob/master/examples/basic_auth/app.py):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_simpleldap import LDAP

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'super secret key'
app.debug = True

app.config['LDAP_HOST'] = 'my-ldap-host.example.com'
app.config['LDAP_REALM_NAME'] = 'LDAP Authentication'
app.config['LDAP_SCHEMA'] = 'ldaps'
app.config['LDAP_PORT'] = 636
app.config['LDAP_BASE_DN'] = 'dc=example,dc=com'
app.config['LDAP_USERNAME'] = 'binduser@example.com'
app.config['LDAP_PASSWORD'] = 'binduser_pw'

app.config['LDAP_OBJECTS_DN'] = 'distinguishedName'
app.config['LDAP_OPENLDAP'] = False

ldap = LDAP(app)


@app.route('/ldap')
@ldap.basic_auth_required
def ldap_protected():
    return 'Welcome, {0}!'.format(g.ldap_username)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

When running the flask app, i'll get an error such as this:

```
LDAPException: Operations error
```

While trying to troubleshoot, i've modified `flask_simpleldap` `__init__.py` file to show the `info` as well as the `desc` of the error, on [line 274](https://github.com/admiralobvious/flask-simpleldap/blob/master/flask_simpleldap/__init__.py#L274); Now i get a bit more info about the error:

```
LDAPException: 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090752, 
comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v2580
```

So, i guess what i need to understand is why my initial bind won't work... do i have something wrong in my `app.config`?

Not sure what the problem could be... `ldapsearch` seems to work from a shell as such:

```
ldapsearch -x -LLL -E pr=200/noprompt -h my-ldap-host.example.com -D "binduser@example.com" -w 'binduser_pw' -b "dc=example, dc=com" -s sub  "(sAMAccountName=binduser)"    | grep distinguishedName


distinguishedName: CN=Bind User,OU=Some_OU,DC=example,DC=com
```

**Other details**:

- I've tried on python2.7 and 3.5, same issues
- Centos 7.2
- Active Directory is my LDAP server

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is going to be helpful, but I've just set `flask_simpleldap` to work with our test Active directory instance. The only relevant difference is that I had to use:

```
app.config['LDAP_USE_SSL'] = True
```

I think I've also seen "Operations Error" when I had invalid DN or username format.

Comment: Ok, that got me binded and past my first error.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Your username must be fully qualified.

```
app.config['LDAP_USERNAME'] = 'uid=binduser,dc=example,dc=com'
```